# Convex polyhedron proof

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, linear-transformations, linear-programming

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q4MP.png)

Let $T:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ a linear transformation. Prove that $T(A)$ is polyhedron.
My answer is the following:
$$T(A) = \{ Tx,x \in A\} $$
let  ${(C^*_i)_{1 \le i \le p}} \subset \mathbb R^m$ , One has:
$$(Tx,C^*_i) = (x,{T^*} C^*_i) = (x,C^{**}_i) \le {\beta _i}^*$$
where $A$ is supposed polyhedron.
Is this correct? thanks.

Comment: Why is $(x,C^{**}_i)\leq \beta_i^\ast$?  How is $\beta_i^\ast$ defined and how do you know the inequality holds?

Comment: because x belongs to A and A is polyhedron.

Comment: But $A$ is defined in terms of $C_i$ not $C^{\ast\ast}_i$.  How do you make that transition?

Comment: if the contant$ C_i$ changes, $A$ can not be a polyhedron ?

Comment: No, but you never defined it.

Comment: See the annexed phto.

Comment: You do not make the relationship between $C_i$ and $C^\ast_i$ clear.  Therefore, there is no connection between your assumptions on $C_i$ and anything else.

Comment: sir, i asked you a quetion: if we change the $C_i$ in the definitoon , is $A$ will still polyhedron? thank you.

Comment: You can change $C_i$, but you would need to prove that you have the same polyhedron.

Comment: if we change the $\beta_i $ and $C_i$....A stille polyhedron...?

Comment: If you change $\beta_i$ and $C_i$, you still get a polyhedron, but it might not be $A$.

Comment: Thankyou sir.. is there an other method to prove that ?

Comment: Hello again, is there any chance or any changes in my proof to be correct ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following solution: Recall that the [Minkowski-Weyl theorem](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~fukuda/soft/polyfaq/node14.html) says that any polyhedron $A$ is given by a sum of a bounded convex set and a cone. In other words, for each $x \in A$ it holds that there are vectors $v_1,...,v_p$, $r_1,...,r_q$ such that
$$
x = \sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_i v_i + \sum_{j=1}^q \mu_jr_j
$$ 
where $\lambda_i, \mu_j \geq 0$ and $\sum \lambda_i = 1$.

Then, by linearity 
$$
Tx = \sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_i Tv_i + \sum_{j=1}^q \mu_jTr_j
$$
so the image of $T(A)$ is given by a convex combination of the vectors $Tv_i$ and a conic combination of the vectors $Tr_j$. By Minkowski-Weyl $T(A)$ is therefore a polyhedron.